# filtering Internet traffic and caching on another machine using a dd-wrt router

Tags: dd-wrt, nat, iptables

In my home network, I have a spare machine which I would like to configure to filter Internet traffic (block ads) as well as cache content.  I would like to tell my DD-WRT router to pass all Internet traffic through this machine.

I do not want to add another NIC and do not want the machine to be directly on the "Internet".  How else can I use this machine to effectively filter and cache all Internet traffic?

I am thinking I could use iptables to do something of this nature, but want to be careful that I am not creating a loop and the traffic cannot get out.

Comment: Does it have not be transparent?  If not then just block all outbound traffic that doesn't come from the filter.

Comment: Yeah, I want to do it transparently.

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for finding that.  I did check their site, but I must have used the wrong keywords.